# Sql join, count references including zeros

Tags: sql, mariadb

I made a simple database containing two tables, 'country' and 'human':

```
+------+---------+
| id   | name    |
+------+---------+
|    1 | Finland |
|    2 | Sweden  |
|    3 | Norway  |
|    4 | Denmark |
+------+---------+

+--------+----------+
| name   | homeland |
+--------+----------+
| Liisa  |        1 |
| Matti  |        1 |
| Holger |        2 |
+--------+----------+
```

This query shows that nobody lives in Norway, but why it says nothing about Denmark?

```
select country.name, count(human.name)
from human
    right join country on human.homeland = country.id
group by homeland;

+---------+-------------------+
| name    | count(human.name) |
+---------+-------------------+
| Norway  |                 0 |
| Finland |                 2 |
| Sweden  |                 1 |
+---------+-------------------+
```

I am using MariaDB, but prefer solutions that works on other DBs too.

Comment: `group by country.name` instead.

Comment: Tip of today: Qualify all columns, at least when several tables are involved. E.g. `human.homeland` instead of just `homeland`.

Comment: Tip 2: Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: @jarih, that was simple one. Thanks. If you make that an answer, I can mark it as working. Btw, why the zero of Norway from my query?

Comment: No one lives in Norway! You have two Finns and one Swede. (LEFT JOIN/RIGHT JOIN will give you those 0 people countries. If you don't want them, do a regular INNER JOIN instead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, *except those who are arguments to set functions*:

```
select country.name, count(human.name)
from country 
    left join human on human.homeland = country.id
group by country.name;
```